# Apply Referencing Outlet to Multiple Buttons (Collection)

Tags: ios, iboutlet, iboutletcollection

I'm trying to set 10 buttons with the same font and style but don't want to create 10 `IBOutlet`s. I've never used a collection before but I believe that is how I minimise code when working with outlets?
How can I put this code into a referencing outlet collection and apply it to all my buttons?

ViewController.h

```
IBOutlet UIButton *label;
```

ViewController.m (ViewDidLoad)

```
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"CooperBlack" size:14]];
```

Comment: You Can use `Custom Cell` as using `UICollectionViewCell`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use IBOutletCollection to connect multiple UIImageViews to the same outlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836930/how-can-i-use-iboutletcollection-to-connect-multiple-uiimageviews-to-the-same-ou)

Answer (score 3):

Here is your properties outlets:

```
@property IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *labels;
```

**And then:**

```
// somewhere in your code
for(UILabel *lbl in self.labels) {
        [lbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
    }
```

Comment: This won't work. I believe he needed `UIButton` not `UILabel`.

Comment: He can change the type to UIButton. @property IBOutletCollection(UIButton), What is the big deal ?

Comment: I've put the @property just outside of the interface ViewController in .h and the for loop in the view did load in .m but in storyboard I can't set the button to new referencing collection. Any ideas why?

Comment: Remember your collection should be of type UIButton, not label. @BrownEye.