# How can you search for a UIImage point in 39 UIImage rectangles within a for loop?

Tags: objective-c

I am new to objective C but have created some moving animations in Xcode 5 and now want to make a simple game. I need a way to check if the center point of an image is within a rectangle the catch is it could be within 39 rectangles.

I could check if the center of the image is within each rectangle using CGRectContainsPoint but this would require 39 if stmts. Like this:

```
if(CGRectContainsPoint(block1.frame, RedAntWorker.center){//found it do something otherwise keep checking}
```

//do this 39 more times for blockn.frame

I would rather use a for loop with one if stmt. Here is what I want to do:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 39; i++) {
 NSString *nameOfImageView = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"block1%d.png", i+1];
    UIImageView *image = nameOfImageView;
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(image.frame, RedAntWorker.center){
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

However this is clearly wrong and at run time I get: UIImageView * with an expression of type NSString *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your image views are outlets, you should use an `IBOutletCollection` as described in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836930/how-can-i-use-iboutletcollection-to-connect-multiple-uiimageviews-to-the-same-ou).