# Why can't I access to nested UIView from viewWithTag method using StoryBoard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I created some UIImageViews inside a nested UIView by Storyboard and I created a different TAG for each UIImageView. This is how the tree of the ViewController looks according to Storyboard:

- ViewController

  - View

    - ViewNested

      - UIImageView1
      - UIImageView1
      - UIImageView1
      - UIImageView1

I have to change programmatically these ImageViews so, to get the images I use the method `viewWithTag` but it doesn't work because it returns `NIL`.
This happens even if I add to my class the `ViewNested IBOutlet` and getting the views using  the following code:

```
// View is the top View with Tag:40            
UIView * view = [self.view viewWithTag:40]; //This works
// The nestedView with Tag:44          
UIView * viewNested = [view viewWithTag:44]; //DOESN'T work it returns NIL even if the TAG is exact
```

Then if I try to access to the imageView using the same method of course, it returns `NIL`. I don't know why, I also tried to use this code to view all the recursive nested view but it seems that they don't exist even if they are present in the storyboard.

```
- (void)showAllSubView:(UIView *)view
{   int i = 0;
    for (UIView * subView in [view subviews]) {
        NSLog(@"%@, tag:%ld", subView, (long)subView.tag) ;
        [self showAllSubView:subView] ;
        i++;
    }
    NSLog(@"Numb of Views %d", i) ;

}
```

The TAGS are 40 for the root View, 44 for the nested and for the images are 1,2,3,4. So the TAGS are all different.

Any help will be appreciate :). Thanks in advance

Comment: Update your question and show what the tag is for each view in your hierarchy.

Comment: Why wan't use IBOutlet?

Comment: If `showAllSubView` says they are not subviews of `viewNested`, what makes you think that they should be?

Comment: To see what's really going on, insert a break-point somewhere in your code where you're sure all the views are loaded, then run this in the debug area console: `po [self.view recursiveDescription]`. It will print the complete view hierarchy, tags included.

Comment: @OMGHaveFun Because I have 18 UIImageViews so I would to access them by TAG not by IBOutlet

Comment: Are you sure viewNested is not nil when you call viewWithTag?

Comment: @Artal I call the viewWithTag method not in the viewDidLoad..my question is why I cannot intercept the views that exist in the Storyboard, I really don't understand this.

Comment: @Tapani I checked that the nestedView is NIL, only the root isn't! I will edit the question

Comment: make sure you added tag for each view in the interface builder.

Comment: @Cris Ok, you can use IBOutletCollection, example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836930/how-can-i-use-iboutletcollection-to-connect-multiple-uiimageviews-to-the-same-ou

Comment: @OMGHaveFun Ok I see this data structure I will test this solution thank you! Do you have any idea about my issue, in your opinion is a normal behaviour of the nested views or there are some mistakes in my methods?

Comment: @Cris     UIImageView *imageView=(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:yourTag];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIImageView *imageView=(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:yourTag];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"]];
```

replace yourTag with UIImageView tag;
replace yourImageName with some Image name

and if you want change only images of ImageViews - you don't need

```
UIView * view = [self.view viewWithTag:40]; //This works
// The nestedView with Tag:44          
UIView * viewNested = [view viewWithTag:44];
```

Also you can change all images:

```
for (int i=0; i<18; i++)
    {
            UIImageView *imageView=(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageName_%d", i];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    }
```