# Have Outlet of many Button iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a Calculator app. if a user press equal I want  to change the background color of all my button(digit 1 to 9) should i have an outlet for each button(each button represent a digit) or there is a way to have one outlet that covers all buttons ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use IBOutletCollection to connect multiple UIImageViews to the same outlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836930/how-can-i-use-iboutletcollection-to-connect-multiple-uiimageviews-to-the-same-ou)

Answer (score 7):

You want an `IBOutletCollection`.

In Objective-C, it would look like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray* buttons;
```

In Swift:

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton] = []
```

Then connect each of your buttons to the buttons outlet in Interface Builder, and you can iterate through each easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop all the elements in the UIView and change it programmatically using the code below

```
for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
    if let btn = view as? UIButton {
         //do your changes here
         btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way

control drag each button to the same outlet from the storyBoard. This should hook up each button to one outlet if I am remembering correctly, give it a try and then update your background colors to see if this works.

Of course yes, you can have an outlet for each button if you wish